# python: algorithm for swapping elements between two arrays

Tags: python

I am analyzing counting [example](https://codility.com/media/train/2-CountingElements.pdf) in python presented by Codility

I don't understand the logic used in the last loop (5 last rows) of this algorithm. 

 Can anybody help please?

The problem:

> You are given an integer `m` (`1 < m < 1000000`) and two non-empty,
>   zero-indexed arrays `A` and `B` of `n` integers, `a0`, `a1`, ... ,
>   `an−1` and `b0`, `b1`, ... , `bn−1` respectively (`0 < ai`, `bi < m`).
>   The goal is to check whether there is a swap operation which can be
>   performed on these arrays in such a way that the sum of elements in
>   array `A` equals the sum of elements in array `B` after the swap. By
>   swap operation we mean picking one element from array `A` and one
>   element from array `B` and exchanging them.

The solution:

```
def counting(A, m):
   n = len(A)
   count = [0] * (m + 1)
   for k in xrange(n):
       count[A[k]] += 1
   return count


def fast_solution(A, B, m):
    n = len(A)
    sum_a = sum(A)
    sum_b = sum(B)
    d = sum_b - sum_a
    if d % 2 == 1:
        return False
    d //= 2
    count = counting(A, m)
    for i in xrange(n):
        if 0 <= B[i] - d and B[i] - d <= m and count[B[i] - d] > 0:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would recommend you is read again the explanations given in the exercise. It already explains what how the algorithm works. However, if you still have problems with it, then take a piece of paper, and some very simple example arrays and go through the solution step by step.

For example, let `A = [6, 6, 1, 2, 3]` and `B = [1, 5, 3, 2, 1]`.

Now let's go through the algorithm.

I assume you understand how this method works:

```
def counting(A, m):
   n = len(A)
   count = [0] * (m + 1)
   for k in xrange(n):
       count[A[k]] += 1
   return count
```

It just returns a list with counts as explained in the exercise. For list A and m = 10 it will return:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Then we go through the main method `fast_solution(A, B, m)`:

`n = 11` (this will be used in the loop)

The sum of A equals `18` and the sum of B equals `12`.

The difference `d` is `-6` (sum_b - sum_a), it is even. Note that if difference is odd, then no swap is available and the result is False.

Then `d` is divided by `2`. It becomes `-3`.

For A we get count `[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]` (as already mentioned before).

Then we just iterate though the list B using `xrange` and check the conditions (The loop goes from 0 and up to but not including 11). Let's check it step by step:

`i = 0`, `B[0] - (-3)` is `1 + 3 = 4`. 4 is greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 10 (remember, we have chosen `m` to be `10`). However, `count[4]` is 0 and it's not greater than 0 (Note the list `count` starts from index `0`). The condition fails, we go further.

`i = 1`, `B[1] - (-3)` is `5 + 3 = 8`. 8 is greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 10. However, `count[8]` is 0 and the condition fails.

`i = 2`, `B[2] - (-3)` is `3 + 3 = 6`. 6 is greater than 0 and less than 10. Also `count[6]` is 2 and it is greater than 0. So we found the number. The loop stops, True is returned. It means that there is such a number in B which can be swapped with a number in A, so that sum of A becomes equal to the sum of B. Indeed, if we swap 6 in A with 3 in B, then their sum become equal to 15.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok,I got the concept. Knowing the difference between arrays B and A, we check if each element of B could be replaced by a number lower by difference/2 (let's call it x), so that the sums of the arrays get equal. 
Fist part of the loop checks if x is in the range of interest (between 0 and m) and the second part checks if x exist in the A, if it exists there (count>0)  then the swap is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get your idea correctly. Here's my understanding:

```
def counting(A, m):
   n = len(A)
   count = [0] * (m + 1)
   for k in xrange(n):
       count[A[k]] += 1
   return count # this essentially build a counter


def fast_solution(A, B, m):
    n = len(A)
    sum_a = sum(A)
    sum_b = sum(B)
    d = sum_b - sum_a
    if d % 2 == 1:
        return False
    d //= 2
    count = counting(A, m) # get the dict
    for i in xrange(n):
        if 0 <= B[i] - d and B[i] - d <= m and count[B[i] - d] > 0:
        # the first two conditions are to verify that B[i]-d exists as a key (index) in counter.
        # then check if there actually exists the value.
        # if count > 0, then you can swap the two to get same sum
            return True
    return False
```

Or rewriting to get:

```
def counting(A, m):
   count = collections.Counter()
   for i in A:
       count[i] += 1
   return count


def fast_solution(A, B, m):
    n = len(A)
    sum_a = sum(A)
    sum_b = sum(B)
    d = sum_b - sum_a
    if d % 2 == 1:
        return False
    d //= 2
    count = counting(A, m) # get the dict
    for i in B:
        if count[i-d]:
            return True
    return False
```

But in any case, this piece of code just check the solution existence with only single swap, be sure to check if that's what you wanted.